# Rascal MPL print id of all traversed nodes in a visit

Tags: visitor-pattern, rascal

Is it possible to print all node ids / values that are traversed in a visit? Take the following code sample:

```
top-down visit(asts) {
    case x: println(typeOf(x));
}
```

I now get all types of the nodes that were visited. I would instead like to know the ids / values of all x that were encountered (without printing the entire tree). In other words, I am curious as to how Rascal traverses the `list[Declaration] asts` containing `lang::java::m3::AST`s.

As a corrolary, is it possible to print direct ascendants / descendants of a Declaration regardless of their type? Or print the total number of children of an ast?

In the documentation (https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/rascal/expressions/visit/) there is no mention of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- in principle a Rascal value does not have an "id". It's structure is its "id" and its id is its structure. You can print a hash if you want, using `md5sum` for example from the IO function: `case value x : println(md5sum(x));`
- Rascal traverses lists from left to right. In `top-down` mode it first visits the entire list and in `bottom-up` mode it goes first to the children.
- printing the total number of nodes in a tree: `(0 | it + 1 | /_ <- t)`
- printing all children of a node: `import Node;`,  `case node n: println(getChildren(n));`
- ascendants are not accessible unless you match deeper and include two levels of nodes in a pattern.

Comment: Ah the Node approach makes the most sense to me. Question: which parts of an AST as defined above are classifiable as a Node and which are not? The documentation is lacking such examples in my opinion.

Comment: Another question: `getChildren(n)` returns `list[value]`, not `list[Node]`. How to retrieve all direct children nodes of a Node?

Comment: some children might not be nodes. So if you want to filter only the nodes that's possible in many ways. One is using a list comprehension: `[ m | node m <- getChildren(n)]`. But beware this will skip over any child which does not match the `node m` pattern.

Comment: To your other question: everything in an AST is `node` if it looks like `name( ..., ...)`, so prefix terms with positional parameters and optional keyword parameters. In Rascal the type system is WYSIWYG, so nodes have different syntax from lists, sets, maps, integers, tuples, and so if something looks like a node, it certainly is a node.

Comment: I think `(0 | it + 1 | node _ <- t)` does not get the right result for the total number of nodes. When I do the same count using `visit()`, I get different answers.

Comment: A slash / in front of node will make the pattern search deep into the tree. This only iterates over the children of the top node. Also change <- to := otherwise the top node is skipped.